# Returning Base64 string from AS3 to Javascript. Is this a bug or feature (or am I wrong?)

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex

During my recent development of a larger project I have met with following strange behavior of AS3 `ExternalInterface` when trying to send a Base64-encoded data from AS3 to Javascript. I have stripped-down the code to the simplest possible version as follows:

`TestSWF.as` file:

```
package {
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class TestSWF extends Sprite {

        public function callTestSWF():String {
            var strToRet:String = '/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+';
            trace(strToRet);
            return strToRet;
        }

        public function TestSWF() {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("CallTestSWF", callTestSWF);
        }
    }
}
```

This file is compiled with Flex-SDK 4.6 using

```
mxmlc -output test.swf -compiler.omit-trace-statements=false -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries -- TestSWF.as
```

The corresponding `index.html` file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test SWF</title>
</head>

<body style="font-family:sans-serif;">

    <script>
        function getStr() {
            var flash = document.getElementById('swfObj');
            var outText = flash.CallTestSWF();
            document.getElementById('fromFlash').innerHTML = outText;
        }
    </script>

    <input type="button" onclick="getStr();" id="sendToFlash"  value="Call Flash"/>

    <hr/>
    <pre id="fromFlash">---</pre>
    <hr/>

    <embed id="swfObj" src="test.swf">

</body>
</html>
```

Now, when this `index.html` is exposed by a web-server and the client browser is equipped by a **debugging** version of the flash-player (v. 20.0), I get a very strange warning

```
WARNING: For content targeting Flash Player version 14 or higher, ExternalInterface escapes strings using JSON conventions. To maintain compatibility, content published to earlier Flash Player versions continues to use the legacy escaping behavior.
```

It is worth to mention that no `JSON` is used anywhere. Notice, that the string returned from AS3 contains the full set of characters used in Base64 code. This warning disappears, when the '`/`' is deleted.

Is this a bug or what is the explanation for this annoying behavior? Any comment is welcome.

Comment: It's a feature. You have a `var strToRet:String` and you are warned `ExternalInterface escapes strings using JSON conventions` so regardless of your using JSON or not, any string going via ExternalInterface will be parsed as such...  Doesn't seem to be a padding issue with the `/` included but you say it works better **without**? Strange

Comment: I suspect a bug. The whole printable ASCII set (chars 32 - 126) work fine **except** `/` and `"`.

Answer (score 1):

This rather annoying warning happens whenever you pass special characters through `ExternalInterface` that used to be escaped differently. In most cases you can just ignore it.

**To elaborate:** prior to Flash Player 14 the internal method used to escape strings passed through `ExternalInterface` had a lot of issues (such JS injection vulnerabilities) that led to developers coming up with workarounds with regex. When the escaping behavior was changed (to use JSON conventions) in Flash Player 14 it would potentially break many developer's prior fixes, so instead of just releasing a breaking change they opted to support legacy escape behavior for SWFs targeting older players, and give a *warning* when strings are passed through `ExternalInterface` that contain characters developers might be trying to escape in some weird way to supported the legacy escape behavior, which will break in the new behavior. In other words, this warning is not saying you are doing something wrong, it's making you aware of a behavior in the Flash Player that has *changed* in regards to some strings you are using. If your strings work as expected the warning is not a problem and you don't need to do anything. That's why I say it's "annoying". It's basically a "legacy API warning" except the API is the same, its the behavior of the existing API that has a legacy behavior you might need to be aware of.

If you search the internet you'll find pieces of this tale all over the place.

If you really want the warning to go away you can encode the special characters. In my experience the easiest thing to do is use `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` on the other end:

HTML:

```
<script>
    function getStr() {
        var flash = document.getElementById('swfObj');
        var outText = decodeURIComponent(flash.callTestSWF());
        document.getElementById('fromFlash').innerHTML = outText;
    }
</script>
```

AS3:

```
public function callTestSWF():String {
    var strToRet:String = encodeURIComponent('/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+');
    trace(strToRet);
    return strToRet;
}
```

Or you can use regex, but personally, in your case I would just ignore the warning knowing your code works correctly and not introduce some fragile regex.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a work-around, not an explanation.  Much more efficient work-around in AS3 is e.g.: `var strToRet:String = originalString.replace(/\//g, "#");`

Comment: How is it not an explanation? Perhaps I wasn't clear: this is an expected warning. Also how is a regex "much more efficient"?

Comment: The warning is definitely **not expected** as it works without warning when transferring any ASCII string without `/` or `"`. What concerns efficiency, this is a very simple example. In my original application I need to transfer several MB binary data encoded in Base64 string, and every `/` is then encoded as 3 chars. Cf. my comment to @VCOne above.

Comment: The warning *is expected* whether *you* expect it or not. I'll try to clarify for you in an edit.

Comment: Aaron, many thanks for your **explanation**. Unfortunately, I was unable to find any such comment in Adobe's documentation. That is why I considered it as a _strange behavior_.

Comment: It is certainly poorly documented and overly alarming, to the extend you might say the warning was poorly implemented. I guess they erred on the side of caution, knowing how hard they try not to break legacy Flash content. Today with Flash Player 20 this warning could frankly be retired or opted out of, IMO.